# Why I obtain this error message when I try to perform this simple query that insert a record inside a table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am pretty new in database and I have the following problem.

On an Oracle DB I have a table named **KM_COUNTRY_AREA** having the following structure:

```
COLUMN NAME          DATA_TYPE           NULLABLE    DATA_DEFAULT   COLUMN_ID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IDCOUNTRYAREA        NUMBER(19,0)          No           (null)             1    
NOMEFOLDER           VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)    Yes          (null)             2    
COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY    NUMBER(19,0)          Yes          (null)             3
```

So the **IDCOUNTRYAREA** field I think that it is an autogenerated field (because the table is created using Hibernate and this field is defienied as **@Id** and **@GeneratedValue** inside the model class).

So now I have to insert some records directly into the DB (I need to do some test) but I am finding some problem writing the insert query, I am following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

and I have create this SQL statment:

```
INSERT INTO KM_COUNTRY_AREA (IDCOUNTRYAREA, NOMEFOLDER, COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY) VALUES (null, "BRAZIL", 715);
```

I have put the first column value to **null** because it have to be autogenerate (but I think that it is wrong).

It don't works and I obtain the following error message:

```
Errore con inizio alla riga 1 nel comando:
INSERT INTO KM_COUNTRY_AREA (IDCOUNTRYAREA, NOMEFOLDER, COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY)
VALUES (null, "BRAZIL", 715)
Errore alla riga del comando:2 Colonna:14
Report errori:
Errore SQL: ORA-00984: colonna non consentita in questo caso
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How can I solve this issue and correctly insert my row into my **KM_COUNTRY_AREA** table?

Tnx

**EDIT-1:**

I tryied to modify using:

```
INSERT INTO KM_COUNTRY_AREA (IDCOUNTRYAREA, NOMEFOLDER, COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY)
VALUES (null, 'BRAZIL', 715);
```

but I obtain the following error message:

```
Errore con inizio alla riga 1 nel comando:
INSERT INTO KM_COUNTRY_AREA (IDCOUNTRYAREA, NOMEFOLDER, COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY)
VALUES (null, 'BRAZIL', 715)
Report errori:
Errore SQL: ORA-01400: impossibile inserire NULL in ("PRC_KM_OWNER"."KM_COUNTRY_AREA"."IDCOUNTRYAREA")
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

it seems that I can't have null for the primary key but it is strange because in Hibernate I definied this field as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long idCountryArea;
```

So I think that its value have to be automatically generated, what is wrong?

Comment: Just because you have some annotation in your Java code doesn't mean that Oracle magically generates values for that column. Read up on how to use sequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `Double quotes` and use `single quotes` for inserting `varchar` data

Also Create a `sequence` to auto generate values

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1

INSERT INTO KM_COUNTRY_AREA 
(IDCOUNTRYAREA,NOMEFOLDER, COUNTRY_IDCOUNTRY)
VALUES (seq.nextval, 'BRAZIL', 715)
```

Comment: Still not work. I have updated my original post inserting an edit at the end of this post in wich I explain the exact problem

Comment: @AndreaNobili - you should not insert NULL value into auto generated column, Remove that column from insert it will get auto generated. updated check now

Comment: I tryied your new solution but I obtain Errore SQL: ORA-01400: impossibile inserire NULL in ("PRC_KM_OWNER"."KM_COUNTRY_AREA"."IDCOUNTRYAREA")
01400. 00000 -  "cannot insert NULL into (%s)"

Comment: @AndreaNobili Looks like you some more columns with `not null` constraint. You have to insert values into those not null columns as well. Example i have used `some_value` you insert proper value

Comment: @AndreaNobili - sorry didn't understand the error completely try now updated

Comment: You missed the , character after seq.nextval but correcting it seems works fine :-) Tnx